# How to use subprocess.call to restart a service in linux?

Tags: python, linux, nginx, subprocess

I want to restart nginx using subprocess.call. I'm using

```
subprocess.call("sudo systemctl restart nginx",shell=True)
```

However, when using `shell=True` the command didn't do anything while, I'm using `shell=False` it said no directory or files "command I implemented the subprocess.call in a button.

Comment: We have no idea why this fails, though. Does `subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "-l"])` succeed? If you have a GUI in front, there is no good way for `sudo` to ask you for a password.

Comment: @tripleee i tried the command you give me and the server responded by no such file or directory "sudo". everytime i drop the shell=False they always return no such file or directory. i tried to call ("./ file.sh",shell=True) a shellscript i made consisting the restart command and it return non-zero exit status 127. and when using shell=False it return no such file...

Comment: If you do not have the `sudo` command installed, that certainly explains why you can't run this code.

Comment: Again, with `shell=False`, you need to split it into a list yourself. But the token `./` is not valid syntax with or without a shell. Do you mean `"./file.sh"`? The way to run that with `shell=False` is `subprocess.call(["./file.sh"])`; notice how I have manually converted the command to a list of tokens (where of course because there is only one token, the list is also just one item).

Comment: @tripleee sorry, now  i get it. i try it and it doesn't return an error but the service itself didn't restart.

Comment: If you can't run `sudo` on the command line then obviously you cannot run it from Python either. Find instructions for how to install `sudo` for your platform (basically `apt-get` for Debian, `yum` for Red Hat, probably something like `emerge` for Gentoo, etc) and how to configure it properly.

Comment: @tripleee I already have sudo installed. just now, i tried to reconfigure the sudo configuration but it stays the same so nothing happened. thanks btw for patiently responding.

Comment: Then if Python can't find `sudo` you have the wrong `PATH` inside Python.  What's the value of `import os; print(os.environ["PATH"])` and how does it differ from your interactive `PATH` in a session where `sudo` does work?

Comment: @tripleee thankyou its working now. :DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `shell=True` and `shell=False` on Unix-like systems is that the shell takes care of breaking up the command line for `exec`, whereas if you don't have a shell, you have to do that yourself.

The shell offers no benefits here, so you can safely drop it.

```
subprocess.call(["sudo", "systemctl", "restart", "nginx"])
```

So in the general case anything which looks like

```
subprocess.something("blah 'blah' \"blah\"", shell=True)
```

needs to be converted into a list without shell quoting to run it without `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.something(['blah', 'blah', "blah"])
```

and of course anything which is specific to the shell (redirection, pipelines, globbing, etc) will need to be replaced with native Python code.

More details at [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) and [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

If your original code didn't work, this also probably won't work, though.